# Is there a way to add more space between the link text and the line of the link?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Is there a way for me to add **more** space between the text of the link and the link that shows up below it. Is this possible in anyway?

Currently I have only found ways to remove the link or change the color of the link but can I space it out?

[image]

So for example, in the above link, is their a way to add a larger gap (space) between the text (- Nelson Mandela) and the line?

HTML code:

```
<a href = "#" id = "link"></a>
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear.

Comment: `a { padding: 10px; }` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use bottom border instead of default bottom line with padding.

```css
a{
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<a href = "#" id = "link">saas</a>
```